# Sort the list while dragging and dropping in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, drag-and-drop

I am using ng-drag-drop for dragging and dropping the list from one div to another. I want to rearrange the list if the drag and drop occur within the div.

Below is my code. is there any library of the same?

I have tried `sortablejs` but no luck and I'm using angular 5

Please suggest

Can primeng allow drag a row on datatable to any component in angular 5?

Add Controls 
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                {{item.name}}

#### Pivot Table

---

Drop Anything here
                                    

                                        {{item.name}}
                                    
                                
                            
                
                
                
                    
                        Drop Anything here
                        
                            {{item.name}}

```
 pivotItems =[
  {name: 'Month', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Year', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Summary', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Calc', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Month1', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Year1', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Summary1', type: 'Controls'},
  {name: 'Calc1', type: 'Controls'}
 ]

  droppedItems = [];
  droppedVerticalItems=[];
  droppedHorizontalItems=[];
  dragEnabled = true;


  onVerticalDrop(e: any) {
    this.droppedVerticalItems.push(e.dragData);
    this.removeDuplicateItem(e.dragData, 'vertical');
    this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.pivotItems);
  }

  onHorizontalDrop(e: any) {
    this.droppedHorizontalItems.push(e.dragData);
    this.removeDuplicateItem(e.dragData, 'horizontal');
    this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.pivotItems);
  }

  removeItem(item: any, list: Array<any>) {
    let index = list.map(function (e) {
      return e.name
    }).indexOf(item.name);
    if(index >-1){
      list.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  onDragStartFn(e:any){
    console.log(e);
  }

  removeDuplicateItem(item: any,dragArea) {
    let list;
    if(dragArea === 'horizontal'){
      list =  this.droppedVerticalItems;
    }
    else  if(dragArea === 'vertical'){
      list =  this.droppedHorizontalItems;
    }
    let index = list.map(function (e) {
      return e.name
    }).indexOf(item.name);
    if(index>-1){
      list.splice(index, 1);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you get data from draggable item when drop it? try log it

Comment: yes i'm getting data when i drop it .. you can see removeItem function in above code